# Docker remove <none> TAG images

Tags: docker

```
root@server:~# docker images -a        
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>                  <none>              5e2dfc857e73        5 days ago          261.6 MB
<none>                  <none>              d053e988f23d        5 days ago          261.6 MB
<none>                  <none>              1d5d4a2d89eb        5 days ago          261.6 MB
<none>                  <none>              ea0d189fdb19        5 days ago          100.5 MB
<none>                  <none>              26c6175962b3        5 days ago          100.5 MB
<none>                  <none>              73d5cec4a0b3        5 days ago          100.5 MB
<none>                  <none>              e19590e1bac1        5 days ago          100.5 MB
```

I've tried the following:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")
```

And the following:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Get the following error:

```
docker: "rmi" requires a minimum of 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
```

Comment: It's a bit late but I have to add this comment for other users. If you use Windows Command Prompt, this won't work. Because Command Prompt doesn't support inner functions. Try the exact lines with Windows PowerShell

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images -a | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')`

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print $3}")`

Comment: `docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)`

Comment: @Karl Morrison: You were nearly there: just missed -a (--all) in `docker images` :)

Answer (score 561, accepted):

You can try and list only untagged images (ones with no labels, or with label with no tag):

```
docker images -q -a | xargs docker inspect --format='{{.Id}}{{range $rt := .RepoTags}} {{$rt}} {{end}}'|grep -v ':'
```

However, some of those untagged images might be needed by others.

[I prefer removing only dangling images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309):

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

As I mentioned for for docker 1.13+ in Sept. 2016 in "[How to remove old and unused Docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309)", you can also do the [`image prune` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/):

```
docker image prune
```

---

[tansadio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9521910/tansadio) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040332/6309):

```
docker images -a | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force
```

But, as noted by [BryanK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325485/bryank): make sure your repository name (or one of your tag names) does not have the sequence of characters '`none`' or those will match the regular expression and get removed too.

---

That being said, [Janaka Bandara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766545/janaka-bandara) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913020/docker-remove-none-tag-images/33913711?noredirect=1#comment78252273_33913711):

> This did *not* remove `<none>`-tagged images for me (e.g. `foo/bar:<none>`); I had to use `docker images --digests` and `docker rmi foo/bar@<digest>`

Janaka references "[How to Remove a Signed Image with a  Tag](https://success.docker.com/KBase/How_to_Remove_a_Signed_Image_with_a_%3Cnone%3E_Tag)" from **[Paul V. Novarese](https://twitter.com/pvnovarese)**:

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
pvnovarese/mprime        latest              459769dbc7a1        5 days ago          4.461 MB
pvnovarese/mprime        <none>              459769dbc7a1        5 days ago          4.461 MB
```

> ### Diagnostic Steps
>
> You can see the difference in these two entries if you use the **[`--digests=true` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-image-digests)** (the untagged entry has the Docker Content Trust signature digest):

```
# docker images --digests=true
REPOSITORY               TAG                 DIGEST                                                                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
pvnovarese/mprime        latest              <none>                                                                    459769dbc7a1        5 days ago          4.461 MB
pvnovarese/mprime        <none>              sha256:0b315a681a6b9f14f93ab34f3c744fd547bda30a03b55263d93861671fa33b00   459769dbc7a1        5 days ago
```

Note that Paul also mentions [moby issue 18892](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18892):

> After pulling a signed image, there is an "extra" entry (with tag `<none>`) in "`docker images`" output.
> This makes it difficult to `rmi` the image (you have to force it, or else first delete the properly-tagged entry, or delete by digest.

---

[This thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-delete-image-with-children/16667/15) also proposes:

> First, you need to change the tag of the specific image you want to remove.
>
> ```bash
> docker tag container_id repo_name:new_tag_name
>
> # example 
> docker tag 1234567er34r davesaah/my-repo:old
> ```
>
> Next, remove the image with the new tag created using docker rmi
>
> ```bash
> docker rmi repo-name:tag
>
> # using the previous example 
> docker rmi davesaah/my-repo:old
> ```
>
> This will remove the dangling image that has dependent child images.

Comment: This did not remove `<none>`-tagged images for me (e.g. `foo/bar:<none>`); I had to use `docker images --digests` and `docker rmi foo/bar@<digest>` as described at https://success.docker.com/KBase/How_to_Remove_a_Signed_Image_with_a_%3Cnone%3E_Tag

Comment: @JanakaBandara Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer (with some additional links)

Comment: for me `sudo docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)`  `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/images/json?filters=%7B%22dangling%22%3A%7B%22true%22%3Atrue%7D%7D: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...] [flags]

Remove one or more images
`

Comment: @JamieHutber "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument. That suggests docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc returns nothing, meaning there is no dangling images?

Comment: Thanks VonC actually it doesn't `hutber@hutber-blade /var/www/dockerfile-wizard $ sudo docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc
sha256:c58f4e4b10b1f862d78f96e90bdf13ffe37993279d0992be46d5c15dad51421e
sha256:db28e821bc3f337caf711a664bc529be5db8894dd73c5b013ad814cc1e9fc21b
sha256:257936750a7d43ae77c713c2cb18342be935de7d3b8fad23d6664fc64acfe753
sha256:6b815cefeb527885b2b9dd831f7f40b05942f00d1367274833a6274154d8ce43
`

Comment: tks, "docker image prune -f" is the official one to remove dangling none:none images

Comment: docker image prune did the job for me.

Comment: The correct answer is from @tansadio below

Comment: Your second line was the solution for me. I'd prefer not to mess around with prune since it can erase absolutely everything I have as a docker image.

Comment: @LucasCamino Good point, especially since I just edited my [`docker prune` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/6309) to explain why there is no "`--dry-run`" mode for those prune commands.

Comment: docker image prune ->  it had work for me!

Comment: @JamieHutber try the following bash command: `value=$(docker images | grep -e "myImageName" | grep -e "<none>" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3); if [ "$value" != "" ]; then docker rmi $value; fi` it works only if there are images of a specified name, and if that specified name has none as tag, though the command can be simplified based on what is suggested by the answer provided by tansadio

Comment: In my occasion the command  `docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)` deleted all the <none>  images.

Answer (score 150):

```
docker images -a | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi
```

You can try this simply

Comment: Have to add `--force` at the end. So the command will look like- 

`docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force`

Comment: @MunimDibosh Just add `-f` at end of the commend from answer.

Comment: Had to add a `-a` to docker images to make it work: `docker images -a | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force`.

Comment: Just make sure your repository name (or one of your tag names) does not have the sequence of characters 'none' or those will match the regular expression and get removed too

Answer (score 63):

Just run this command:

```
docker image prune --filter="dangling=true"
```

Comment: I started with docker image prune. however, the dangling=true removed the stubborn ones.

Comment: This should be the correct answer @basickarl

Answer (score 62):

[docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) removes all dangling images (those with tag none). docker image prune -a would also remove any images that have no container that uses them.

The difference between dangling and unused images is explained in [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142528/docker-what-is-a-dangling-image).

Answer (score 32):

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#show-untagged-images-dangling) you can list only untagged (dangling) images with

```
$ docker images -f "dangling=true"
```

and redirect them to `docker rmi` command like that:

```
$ docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q) --force
```

Notice `-q` param thats only show numeric IDs of containers.

Comment: Isn't it similar to what I proposed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913711/6309) in 2015?

Comment: Downvote. This is again another post which is repeating already given answers.

Answer (score 25):

this worked in my case

```
docker image rm -f $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Remove images which have `none` as the repository name using the following:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Remove images which have `none` tag or repository name:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "none" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Answer (score 14):

> You may check if the **filter 'dangling' is no more working**

```
$ docker images -f “dangling=true” -q
Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'dangling'
```

> Use **docker system prune** to remove the dangling images

```
$ docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all dangling build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

You may use `--force` for not prompt for confirmation

```
$ docker system prune --force
```

Answer (score 11):

docker container prune to remove all stopped containers firstly, then docker image prune to remove all dangling images.

```
docker container prune
docker image prune
```

Answer (score 10):

You can go `docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`.  See the [images documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering) for more options.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                      <none>              94870cda569b        4 seconds ago       673MB
python                      2.7                 320a06f42b5f        10 days ago         673MB
mysql                       latest              e799c7f9ae9c        2 months ago        407MB
gcavalcante8808/semaphore   latest              86e863e11461        2 months ago        537MB
redis                       latest              e32ef7250bc1        2 months ago        184MB
rabbitmq                    3.6.9-management    7e69e14cc496        2 months ago        179MB
rabbitmq                    3.6.9               eb2e4968538a        2 months ago        179MB
jordan/rundeck              latest              6d40b57b1572        2 months ago        660MB
rabbitmq                    3.5.6-management    dbfe8d18809a        19 months ago       304MB

$ docker rmi $(docker images --format '{{.ID}}' --filter=dangling=true)
Deleted: sha256:94870cda569b8cf5f42be25af107d464c993b4502a1472c1679bf2d213b6c0a6
```

Comment: just doing `docker image prune --filter="dangling=true"` will work no need for the listing

Answer (score 10):

To remove all images with `none` we have to be sure that we removed all stopped containers which they can use
run:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

then we can remove all images:

```
docker image prune
```

Answer (score 10):

```
docker rmi --force $(docker images -q --filter "dangling=true")
```

Answer (score 8):

Following will remove all the `<none>` images

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep none | awk '{print $3}')
```

You can force removal by changing `docker rmi` to `docker rmi -f` although I do not recommend doing that.

Some of the `<none>` images could be related to other images so to be on safe side don't use `-f` tag.

Answer (score 8):

**First solution:**

1. First delete containers that are not used.

   ```
   docker ps -a | grep -v Up | awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs docker rm
   ```
2. Delete all containers with none tags.

   ```
   docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi
   ```

---

**Second solution delete all with:**

```
$ docker system prune -a


WARNING! This will remove:
- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all images without at least one container associated to them
- all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use this commend in docker :

```
docker image prune
```

and for all container:

```
docker container prune
```

Answer (score 6):

I have found `docker image prune -f` most useful and I use it all the time during my day to day work, using the tag `-f` will not prompt for confirmation. More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest solution to remove dangling (`<none>`) images should be:

```
docker image prune
```

Optionally you can add `--force` or `-f` to disable the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

`docker system prune` will do the trick, it removes

```
- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all dangling images
- all dangling build cache
```

*But use it, with the caution!*

Comment: you are the boss!

Comment: Downvote. This repeats the answer of @Chetabahana which was some months earlier.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the images using their IDs:

```
# docker rmi 5e2dfc857e73 d053e988f23d ...
```

Comment: This answer is by far the simplest.

Answer (score 4):

All

Sharing the PowerShell command for windows lovers (just in case you don't have bash, grep or awk)

```powershell
(docker images) -like '*<none>*' | ForEach-Object { 
  $imageid=($_ -split "\s+")[2]
  docker rmi -f $imageid
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
docker image rm $(docker images | grep none)
```

Comment: Proceed with caution, this will also delete images that contain 'none' in the image name.

Answer (score 3):

100% works: `docker images | grep none | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f`

Answer (score 3):

i've found this for windows:

```
powershell -Command "docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)"
```

reference:
https://gist.github.com/sebagomez/b00bd9e3610abab55fefe3d69f3708ad

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command to remove the images with [docker rmi](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)

```
docker images --filter "dangling=true"
```

Comment: Prune the containers first so that the images aren't being "used" by stopped containers . Then delete the dangling images.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all exited containers

```
docker rm $(docker container ls -a -f status=exited -q)
```

or remove containers according to a pattern

```
docker images -a | grep "pattern" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that helped me here was

`docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force`

I had 2 images . These were also relatively large at 160MB and I didn't want them.

I tried `docker images prune`, but it didn't help.

`docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi`
This command returned the following:

`Error response from daemon: conflict: 0d1227b90e3a cannot be deleted (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container c2c01a8c0cc9. Error response from daemon: Conflict: 791026064837 cannot be deleted (must be forced) - image used by stopped container 53dee16ceb19.`

There were also still containers that needed these images.

With `docker container ls -a | grep "c2c01a8c0cc9"` I could check which dependency it was.

**With:**

`docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force`

**I have now deleted the  images.**

Since I no longer need this container, I deleted it with: `docker container rm <container_name>`

Answer (score 2):

With Docker Desktop for Windows you can get rid of the dangling images with

```
docker image prune
```

Answer (score 2):

Pruning all images with force would solve your issue

> `docker image prune -a --force`

Answer (score 1):

To remove dangling images please use :

```
docker image rm $(docker images --format "{{.ID}}" --filter "dangling=true")
```

Please refer to my answer here for a more detailed description : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445664/292327

Answer (score 1):

The below command is working for me. this is just simple grep "" images and get the docker image id and removed all the images.  Simple single command as it has to.

`docker rmi $(docker images |grep "<none>"| awk '{print $3}')`

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of tansadio's answer:

If you are getting following error:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete <> (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container <>
```

You can force it with `--force`:

```
docker images | grep none | awk '{ print $3; }' | xargs docker rmi --force
```

Answer (score 1):

try this to see list docker images ID with tag `<none>`

```
docker images -a | awk '/^<none>/ {print $3}'
```

and then you can delete all image with tag `<none>`. this worked for me.

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a | awk '/^<none>/ {print $3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple and clear,

Even I took 3 days to understand this simple and crisp error.

**The docker image is not built successfully**

```
Step 7/13 : COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /root/.jupyter/
 ---> bf29ce6fe6dc
Step 8/13 : COPY notebooks /notebooks
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder776981166/notebooks: no such file or directory
anarchist@anarchist-desktop:~/Documents/sam/dockerDem$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              bf29ce6fe6dc        9 seconds ago       1.27GB
ubuntu              16.04               a51debf7e1eb        3 weeks ago         116MB
```

Then I removed the 8th line from Dockerfile, it was signal success this time.

```
Successfully built b6724370f8ca
Successfully tagged dem:expo
anarchist@anarchist-desktop:~/Documents/sam/dockerDem$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 dem:expo
[I 06:11:38.984 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 06:11:39.011 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /
[I 06:11:39.011 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 06:11:39.011 NotebookApp] http://(296d81166725 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=496feb282ef749c05277ef57a51e8a56fedb1c6b337b9f92
```

It says successfully tagged dem:expo, this line is imp during docker process.

Answer (score 0):

docker rmi -f $(docker images -a|awk 'NR > 1 &&  $2 == "" {print $3}')

Answer (score -2):

The dangling images are ghosts from the previous builds and pulls, simply delete them with : 
**docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)**

Comment: The OP states that he did try this exact command already but it failed. Also, this answer has been given at least twice already.

Answer (score -4):

try

`docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | awk 'NR> 1 || $2 = "<none>" {print $3}')`
, while there may be cleaner commands

Updated

Comment: That will *also* remove images which are not tagged <none> which is a big nono.

Comment: I have upated my answer

Comment: The command `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a | awk 'NR> 1 || $2 = "" {print $3}` does not do anything!

Comment: I came across this a month back and it was all good because I read this comment and didn't use this command. I came back again, forgot to read this comment, and bam, all my images are gone.

Answer (score -8):

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

Stated the following images where in use. I think this command gets rid of unwanted images.

Comment: doesn't this remove all images?

Comment: this removes all unused images and it should not be marked as the correct answer.