# What is a dangling image and what is an unused image?

Tags: docker, docker-image

In the docker [documentation of docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) it is possible to use the -a flag to

> Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones

and later

> Remove all dangling images. If -a is specified, will also remove all images not referenced by any container.

Q: What are `dangling` images?
Q: What's the difference between `dangling` and `unused` images?

Comment: docker image prune (without -a) does exactly the same though

Comment: It fails when you use that in jenkins, we will lose the docker backup in production if we are dependent on docker image cache. `prune` is not recomanded in production/

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224187/269514 by @tgogos, helped me elucidated the confusion.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

An **unused** image means that it has not been assigned or used in a container. For example, when running `docker ps -a` - it will list all of your exited and currently running containers. Any images shown being used inside any of containers are a "used image".

On the other hand, a **dangling** image just means that you've created the new build of the image, but it wasn't given a new name. So the old images you have becomes the "dangling image". Those old image are the ones that are untagged and displays "`<none>`" on its name when you run `docker images`.

When running `docker system prune -a`, it will remove all stopped containers, images and networks without a container associated, and build cache. Be Careful!

Comment: According to the documentation when running docker prune without -a only dangling images are removed. -a will ensure that unused images are also deleted right? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: That is correct, -a will [remove all unused images not just dangling ones](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

Comment: Very interesting. So a dangling image can be used by a container.
[Note: Docker warns you if any containers exist that are using these untagged images.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#filtering)

Comment: `docker system prune --all --filter "until=24h"` preserves recent images also

Comment: According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#extended-description `docker system prune -a` removes stopped containers too. So it should remove images associated only with exited containers too, right?

Comment: I run `docker system prune`, but when I run `docker images` after, I still have all the untagged (`<none>`) images there. Why is that?

Comment: docker system prune --all --filter is not suggested for production. Be carefull doing this in production server.

Comment: Why not @JinnaBalu? It seems like a regular prune is the only way to avoid the disk filling up in production environments where your systemd units autoupdate images. Using the filter flag will help you with caching images that will save resources on future updates.

Comment: because We end up deleting non dangling, we may delete unused, which may be used for rollback to previous version.@deed02392

Comment: It's not just that you didn't give it a tag, there are more ways to _dangle_ an image. E.g.: `docker build -t foo:latest .` then change some code, then `docker build -t foo:latest .` again. This will result in the `foo:latest` tag being applied to the newer image but the tag `foo:latest` can only refer to one image, so the image it previously referred to (from the first build in this example) now has no tag, and becomes _dangling_. Any time a tag is newly applied, there is a chance that whatever image that tag was previously assigned to may now have no other tags and would become _dangling_.

Comment: "Therefore any images being used in a container, whether they have been exited or currently running, will NOT be affected". This is just wrong.
When running docker system prune -a, it will remove all non running containers, and therefore will also remove the images that use them.

Comment: is there a way to list the unused image before prune them? like a dry-run thing?

Comment: `docker system prune -a` removes the following 1. all stopped containers 2. all networks not used by at least one container 3. all images without at least one container associated to them 4. all build cache.

I thought it would only remove dangling images, but that is not the case. Be careful!

Comment: Why not just call them "untagged" or "unnamed" images instead of "dangling" images. "Untagged" is self-descriptive.

Comment: What if there is an image that is `<none> ... In use (dangling)`? Why is it named `<none>` after rebuilding images? The old ones became "Unused", are the new ones "<none>" simply because the name was taken by the now obsolete image? How do I fix it? (Delete the old one and make the new take its name.)

Answer (score 90):

### Safest and Easiest way to cleanup Dangling Images

```
docker images --quiet --filter=dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

Docker images consist of multiple layers. Dangling images, are layers that have no relationship to any tagged images. They no longer serve a purpose and consume disk space.

> **Note: I recommend not to use `prune` in production, because `docker system prune -a` will remove all the images which are not referenced by the container, by which we can't roll back to the previous release.**

To list dangling images by adding the filter flag, `-f` with a value of `dangling=true` to the `docker images`.

#### List Dangling images

```
docker images -f dangling=true
```

#### Remove Dangling Images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

OR

```
docker images --quiet --filter=dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

When we run any cron jobs to delete tha dangling stuff use the above to make sure the job runs successfully. Like in Jenkins if we run a free style job with beloow commad job will never fail even if no dangling stuff exists in the machine.

This is the safest and easiest way to cleanup dangling images and get back our disk space back for use.

Comment: what about docker image prune? Docs say: "Remove all dangling images. If -a is specified, will also remove all images not referenced by any container."
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#related-commands

Comment: @herm, from the bottom of the page you referenced "Note: You are prompted for confirmation before the prune removes anything, but you are not shown a list of what will potentially be removed". I think the point in this answer is that you can get a list of the dangling images, which you then explicitly specify to be removed, as opposed to blindly removing all dangling images with prune.

Comment: The images having name and tag as none in `docker images` are dangled. How to check their size? Also, the images having name and tag as none in `docker images -a` are intermediate images. Can they be deleted and how to check their size?

Comment: Can these dangling images be fixed?

Comment: Fixing is possible but not needed. Dangling images can be re-tagged back to the image, but when we have multiple images, we don't know which image id belongs to which app. Better to delete dangling images.

Answer (score 27):

Images in docker are referenced by a **sha256 digest**, often referred to as the **image id**. That digest is all you need for the image to exist on the docker host. Typically, you will have **tags** that point to these digests, e.g. the tag 'busybox:latest' currently points to image id c30178c523... on my system.

Multiple tags can point to the same image, and any tag can be changed to point to a different id, e.g. when you pull a new copy of busybox:latest or build a new version of your application image.

**Dangling images** are images which do not have a tag, and do not have a **child image** (e.g. an old image that used a different version of `FROM busybox:latest`), pointing to them. They may have had a tag pointing to them before and that tag later changed. Or they may have never had a tag (e.g. the output of a `docker build` without including the tag option).

These are typically safe to remove as long as no containers are still running that reference the old image id. **The main reason to keep them around is for build caching purposes.**

In addition, you may have downloaded images that you are not currently used by containers (including stopped containers). These are entirely different from dangling images and may be safe to remove as long as you don't plan to use them in the future or don't mind downloading another copy when you do need them.

Comment: While a docker build is running (the process in which it creates layers and possible candidates for future dangling images), in a new window if I run docker image prune, then, will it affect the build in progress in any way?

Comment: @variable there could be a race condition in there, but typically the running container for a build step will result in the image being identified as in use. The worst that might happen is either the prune throws an error, or the build does, and you'd have to rerun it. I'd look into whether you can limit your prune to avoid images you are currently using to build since a successful prune will result in future builds needing to download images again.

Comment: Are intermediary images (those that have none name/tag showing upon running `docker images -a`) also called dangled images? Do they get cleared with docker image prune?

Comment: I don't have those in my environment anymore (using buildkit here), so I'd recommend trying yourself in a lab environment to see what happens.

Comment: That said, deleting the untagged "images" from the intermediate stages is fairly pointless, unless you delete the final tagged image, all the layers are reused in a later image and can't be deleted. If you do delete them, you destroy your build cache and cause all future images to take more time to build and disk space to store.

Answer (score 17):

**Dangling images** are **untagged** images. The following command gives a list of dangling images.

```
docker images --filter "dangling=true"
```

`docker image prune` deletes all dangling images.

**Unused images** are images that have tags but currently not being used as a container. You may or may not need it in future.

`docker image prune -a` delete all dangling as well as unused images.

You generally don't want to remove all unused images until some time. Hence it is better to remove with a filter.

`docker image prune -a -f --filter "until=6h"`

Comment: 1) Does `docker image prune -a -f --filter "until=6h"` also delete dangling images?

Comment: 2) In your last command you mention `docker image prune  -f --filter "until=6h"` - since there is no -a - then how come it will remove unused images?

Comment: @variable, The sample on the docker documentation shows `$ docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=2017-01-04T00:00:00"`.  Using the -a with filter is the right way to go if you want to remove both dangling and unused images.

Comment: For docker-1.13 on CentOS 7, 'docker image prune' doesn't delete all dangling images as reported by 'docker images -f dangling=true'. The latter shows images that have either the repository or tag as '<none>'. The former deletes only images that have the repository and tag as 'none'. You'll have lots of images with the repository set but tag='none' after the former command.

Answer (score 17):

**Dangling images** are layers that have no relationship to any tagged images. They no longer serve a purpose and consume disk space.

An **unused image** is an image that has not been assigned or used in a container.

**To list dangling images:**

```
docker images -f dangling=true
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw useful commands (aliases) for removing dangling images, courtesy of andyneff here: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-delete-cache/5753:

```
alias docker_clean_images='docker rmi $(docker images -a --filter=dangling=true -q)' 
alias docker_clean_ps='docker rm $(docker ps --filter=status=exited --filter=status=created -q)'
```

> The first one
>   cleans all dangling images. This is useful for removing intermediate
>   images left over from multiple builds. The second one is for removing
>   stopped containers. These are aliases I use for routine maintenance
>
> If you want to remove ALL of your cache, you first have to make sure
>   all containers are stopped and removed, since you cannot remove an
>   image in use by a container. So something similar

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q) docker_clean_ps docker rmi $(docker images
-a -q)
```

> This would kill and remove all images in your cache.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In the images screenshot, "none" name are dangling images.
A dangling image just means that you've created the new build of the image, but it wasn't given a new name. So the old images you have becomes the "dangling image". Those old image are the ones that are untagged and displays "" on its name when you run docker images.

`docker system prune -a`, it will remove both unused and dangling images. Therefore, any images being used in a container, whether they have been exited or currently running, will NOT be affected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command too. This command only deletes the dangling ones.
Remove “dangling images” using the command

```
 $docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dangling image is one that isn't tagged, and isn't referenced by any container.

https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/