# How to delete docker images in Jenkins Job

Tags: shell, docker

I want to delete the remains of some Docker-operations from within Jenkins.

But somehow the following line does not work...

The issue seems to be with the parenthesis.

Any advice?

```
if [ docker images -f dangling=true -q|wc -l > 0 ]; then docker rmi --force $(docker images -f dangling=true -q);fi
```

Comment: `docker images --quiet --filter=dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Newer versions of Docker now have the `system prune` command.

To remove dangling images:

```
$ docker system prune
```

To remove dangling as well as unused images:

```
$ docker system prune --all
```

To prune volumes:

```
$ docker system prune --volumes
```

To prune the universe:

```
$ docker system prune --force --all --volumes
```

Comment: `docker system prune` will remove all unused data(all stopped containers, all networks not used, all dangling images...), if only want to remove **dangling** images, `docker image prune` is much better.

Comment: `docker system prune` is not recomanded when you don't have backup. Use the specific command to specific cases.

Comment: Will this remove images of other jobs currently running?

Answer (score 1):

[docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) deletes all dangling images. Docker image prune -a deletes unused images too. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142528/docker-what-is-a-dangling-image) explains what dangling and unused images are. 
In short: Dangling image --> No tag, unused images --> no container attached.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, herm.
Unfortunately "docker image" does not exist on my machine...
Might have been the cleaner, shorter solution...

Comment: You mean docker image prune does not exist? That is a relatively new command but docker image ls and others are old.

Comment: Yes it does not exist....
The docker documentation also shows a * beneath docker image.
But I don't know what that star means.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Dangling Images

Use `-xargs` will need `--no-run-if-empty` (-r) to bypass executing `docker rmi` with no arguments

```
docker images --quiet --filter=dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

Use normar bash comand to check and delete

```
 if docker images -f "dangling=true" | grep ago --quiet; then
    docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
 fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the output of the docker images command and then use it:

```
images=$(docker images -f dangling=true -q); if [[ ${images} ]]; then docker rmi --force ${images}; fi
```