# During image prune, does filter apply to unused image or dangled image or both?

Tags: docker, docker-image

docker image prune -a -f --filter="label=xyz"

Does the filter apply to unused image or dangled image or both?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799540/3007402

Comment: This question is about prune. The link is about images

Comment: You have specified `-a` which means all.

Comment: $ docker image prune -a <- this command says: WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them. Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]. Note it does not mention about dangled images