# How can I delete a docker images by their tag <none> and repository name?

Tags: docker

I would like to ask if it's possible to delete docker images for its tag or the created label, I have something like this:

```
Repository                     TAG             IMAGE_ID       CREATED          SIZE

registry.someRegistry.         latest          fa8767676       5 hours ago     119MB
registry.someRegistry.         <none>          878787874       29 hours ago    119MB
registry.someRegistry.         <none>          jkj7jjjk4       2 days ago      119MB
registry.someRegistry.         <none>          d99090iii       3 days ago      119MB
```

I need to remove all the images but not the most recently one in this case is the one tagged with latest or the one with the most recent Created date. I can use the next command to delete all the images until 5 hours of creation, but it's not appropriate, because I could delete more images not just the last one, would be better to delete images by the tag=latest.

```
docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=5h"
```

I need also an additional filter for the registry I think, in order to remove just the images for the registry I need.

Any good way to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142528/what-is-a-dangling-image-and-what-is-an-unused-image, Please check here

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be the `rmi` command, i.e.:

```
docker rmi 878787874
```

This is a "remove image" command and uses the IMAGE_ID you list.

Comment: No, because I don't know what is the id of the images that I need to remove and could be any number 2 to 1000 for example. So I. need to implement a process to remove all of this dangling images.

Answer (score 2):

I have to modify the command slightly to have it run:

```
sudo docker rmi $(sudo docker images | grep "<none>" | awk {'print $3'})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the replies were helpful, and there does not seem to be another thread either. It is way too late but I had the same problem and found this solution:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "<none>" | grep "registry.someRegistry." | awk {'print $3'})
```

This is not 100% proof because `grep` looks for a string in the name *and* the tag, so theoretically if your registry name appears in some tag and vice versa you could accidentally delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to find all dangling images from one specific repository with

```
docker images repository --filter dangling=true
```

If you want to filter by more than one repository based on the registry, it is also possible to do

```
docker images --filter=reference='registry/someRegistry/*:*' --filter dangling=true
```

Once you have the list of the ones you want to remove you can do it with:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter=reference='registry/someRegistry/*:*' --filter dangling=true -q)
```

Edit to add that the wildcard `*` does not apply to `/`, so if the registry has a more complex folder structure, the expression should be amended to something like

```
'registry/someRegistry/*/*:*'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove dangling images with filter

```
 docker images --filter dangling=true
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to remove the ones from a specific repo name not all of them, I need to keep just the latest one and remove the dangling or the ones tagged with <none>