# "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument

Tags: docker

I have a list of untagged containers:

```
dockerizer@docker1:~/zookeeper$ docker images -a
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              46371a3fcd90        12 hours ago        783MB
zookeeper           latest              e85300ce33a1        12 hours ago        783MB
<none>              <none>              5dc40a99a229        12 hours ago        783MB
<none>              <none>              cf203e8e381d        12 hours ago        783MB
<none>              <none>              662536a7dd7c        12 hours ago        740MB
<none>              <none>              fb43b0c06cb3        12 hours ago        783MB
servery             latest              0226f44159c2        2 days ago          51.8MB
<none>              <none>              e25dad0578e1        2 days ago          51.8MB
consul              latest              d686c08d0dc8        3 days ago          51.8MB
ubuntu              latest              747cb2d60bbe        2 weeks ago         122MB
openjdk             latest              74c95c985a85        2 weeks ago         740MB
```

and try to delete with:

```
dockerizer@docker1:~/zookeeper$ docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `docker images -f "dangling=true" -q` return any output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means you don't have any dangling images.

Seeing image with tag none does not mean it is dangling, as I explained in "[Docker remove `<none>` TAG images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913711/6309)"

> After pulling a signed image, there is an "extra" entry (with tag ) in "docker images" output.
>   This makes it difficult to `rmi` the image (you have to force it, or else first delete the properly-tagged entry, or delete by digest.

```
docker images --digests=true
```