# How to remove <none> images after building successfull

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

After I build my image, there are a bunch of images. When I try to delete them I get “image has dependent child images” errors. Is there anyway to clean this up?

These do NOT work:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker rmi $(docker images | grep “^” | awk “{print $3}”)
docker rmi $(docker images -f “dangling=true” -q)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker remove <none> TAG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913020/docker-remove-none-tag-images)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
docker rmi `docker images | grep "<none>" | awk {'print $3'}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - although code/config snippets might provide some limited short-term help, a proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers will help for *docker* cli.

In k8s 1.24+ versions docker is replaced by ***nerdctl***

to delete  tag images with *nerdctl*, one can use `--names` flag of nerdctl command.

```
nerdctl images --names | grep sha256 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs nerdctl rmi
```

Comment: You can't usually directly log into Kubernetes nodes to run commands like this, and you wouldn't directly build images on Kubernetes nodes as described in the question.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are correct. 
Answer still holds true without kubernetes for one who uses nerdctl

Comment: This helped me out using Rancher Desktop with `containerd` backend on OSX. I had loads of images named `<none>:<none>`. I had to add `--namespace k8s.io` to both `nerdctl` invocations, and I also limited the regexp to only match `sha256` at the start of the line (`grep '^sha256`). Full command: `nerdctl -n k8s.io images --names  | grep '^sha256' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs nerdctl -n k8s.io rmi`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep none | awk '{print $3}')
```

You can add -f to force image removal but I do not recommend doing so. If you cannot remove the images with the command above that means it is in partially in use or stopped containers are using the images you are trying to remove.

You can always check the stopped or Existed containers with

```
docker ps -a
```

Here, the Status column will indicate the container status.

Answer (score -1):

docker rmi `docker images -a | grep "<none>" | awk {'print $3'}`

Adding `-a` is required.