# Docker remove image and container before creating

Tags: docker

I have the following script, which creates the docker image and container as expected.

```
echo "password" | sudo -S docker stop /nexct-approval-service-container | xargs sudo docker rm
echo "docker build ..."
echo "password" | sudo -S docker build . -t nexct-approval-service-image:latest
echo "docker run ..."
echo "password" | sudo -S docker run -t --network=host -p 8081:8081 --name nexct-approval-service-container nexct-approval-service-image
```

As you can see I am creating a container and image with the following names:

```
nexct-approval-service-container
nexct-approval-service-image
```

However, what I cannot get to work is the following line:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S docker stop /nexct-approval-service-container | xargs sudo docker rm
```

My intention is to remove the container and image if it exists before I create a new one. What I am finding however, when I do `sudo docker images` is that my list of images continues to grow.

**Question**

How can I build my images with the specific name, but stop a new one from being built each time?

More info:

As you can see, a number of images called `<none>` are left below after each build.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
nexct-approval-service-image   latest              7359e1ff2138        21 seconds ago       557MB
<none>                         <none>              c4f98256b401        About a minute ago   557MB
<none>                         <none>              908eebf0227a        2 minutes ago        557MB
<none>                         <none>              8b6b0cb01773        3 minutes ago        557MB
openjdk                        14                  cdc43cc23d2d        6 days ago           511MB
```

Comment: The later sudo doesn't see the password in your pipe chain. Why don't you just add your user to the docker group?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not experienced at docker. How do I add the user to the group?

Comment: Even if I add the password, it is still not clearing my legacy images: `echo "password" | sudo -S docker stop /nexct-approval-service-container | echo "password" | xargs sudo docker r`. I get the following warning:  `Error: No such container: password`. So I have obviously done it wrong.

Comment: `usermod -aG docker $USER`, start a fresh terminal/ssh session and all docker commands should work without sudo.

Comment: Thanks, now I can run the commander without `sudo`. But the it is still not removing the image.

Comment: Every time you `docker build` an image, the old one remains behind with the `<none>` tags; you need to `docker rmi` images separately from `docker rm` containers.  [Docker remove <none> TAG images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913020/docker-remove-none-tag-images) has some further discussion of cleaning these up (note that the top answers there predate some useful Docker commands that simplify the process).

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you.  That's the solution. I now can remove the images.