# How to create a persistent volume claim in the local Minikube cluster?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have installed Docker Desktop, Minikube, and Kubernetes (K8s) command line tools on Windows 10 and I am using Git bash. I created a FastAPI web service that logs some information. This is the content of the `requirements.txt` file:

```
fastapi[all]
```

And this is the content of the `app/main.py` file, containing the web service code:

```py
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI

logging.basicConfig(filename="my.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s")
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    logging.info("Inside the `read_root` function.")
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/item/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int):
    item_message = "This is the item message."
    logging.info(f"The item_id is the following: {item_id}")
    return {"item_id": item_id, "item_message": item_message}
```

I have two simple API that logs to the `my.log` file. I created a docker image so that it can be deployed in the local Minikube cluster. The content of the `Dockerfile` file is:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

I specified the `python:3.9-alpine` as the base image because it has fewer security vulnerabilities than most of the [Python docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags). I run the web service on the 8000 port using the Uvicorn webserver.

Next, I started the local Minikube cluster and pushed the docker image into it:

```bash
minikube start
eval $(minikube docker-env)
docker build -t fastapi-image .
```

The `eval $(minikube docker-env)` command reuses the Docker daemon inside the Minikube cluster. This means that I can just build docker images using Minikube's Docker daemon which speeds up local experiments. When listing the images with the `minikube image ls` command, I can see my docker image.

After that, I created a simple K8s deployment with one replica set and a service listening on the 8000 port. The `deployment.yml` manifest file is the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi
          image: fastapi-image
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fastapi-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: fastapi
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
```

Note that I added the `imagePullPolicy: Never` configuration because the `fastapi-image` is already in the Minikube Docker registry so Kubernetes does not attempt to download the specified image.

I created the resource from the manifest file and started a service tunnel for the FastAPI service:

```bash
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
minikube service fastapi-service
```

It opens up a browser window that serves the application. If I visit the Swagger UI on the http://127.0.0.1:12345/docs site and try out the APIs, I will get entries in the log file. To check the logs, I entered the Pod instance with the `kubectl exec -it <fastapi-deployment-pod> -- sh` command.

However, if the Pod dies (e.g. running `kubectl delete -f deployment.yml`) then the log entries are lost. I would like to persist the log files even if the Pod was deleted. To store the log files, I would like to create a persistent volume (PV) and then request storage using a persistent volume claim (PVC).

References:

- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/
- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/
- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a persistent volume (PV) and a corresponding persistent volume claim (PVC) object in the `deployment.yml` manifest file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-persistent-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: /persistent_volume/logs
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - minikube
---
```

The storage class name is the [local-storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) which has the `WaitForFirstConsumer` mode by default. It delays the binding and provisioning of a PersistentVolume until a Pod using the PersistentVolumeClaim is created. It reserves 1 GiB data with `ReadWriteOnce` [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes). The `nodeAffinity` section ensures that we select the node from the Minikube cluster. The local path will be important later.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: local-persistent-volume-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
---
```

The PVC requests local storage with a `ReadWriteOnce` access mode and up to 100 MiB capacity. The deployment will refer to the `local-persistent-volume-claim` PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fastapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi
          image: fastapi-image
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: local-storage
              mountPath: /var/log/fastapi_app
      volumes:
        - name: local-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: local-persistent-volume-claim
---
```

First, we mount the `/var/log/fastapi_app` path in the FastAPI container. It is also necessary to describe the `volumes` in the deployment. Use the previously created `local-persistent-volume-claim` PVC.

Before the new deployment, the logging section has to be adapted in the `main.py` file:

```py
from pathlib import Path

log_path = Path("/var/log/fastapi_app")
filename = str(log_path / "my.log") if log_path.exists() else "my.log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s")
```

It sets the mounted `/var/log/fastapi_app` path. If it does not exist (e.g. when testing the application without K8s deployment), it will log to `my.log` file in the application root folder. Now, rebuild the new docker image:

```bash
docker build -t fastapi-image .
```

Check out the new image with the `minikube image ls` command. You may want to delete the unused docker image (`docker.io/library/<none>:<none>`) using the `docker image prune` command.

Almost done! One important thing is to create a persistent volume path on the Minikube cluster. First, we need to connect to the cluster:

```bash
minikube ssh
```

And then create the persistent volume which was described in the `PersistentVolume` K8s object:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /persistent_volume/logs
```

Exit the Minikube cluster. And, then, finally, you can create the new deployment:

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
persistentvolume/local-persistent-volume created
persistentvolumeclaim/local-persistent-volume-claim created
deployment.apps/fastapi-deployment created
service/fastapi-service created
```

Note that the service part is not changed. Tunnel the FastAPI service:

```bash
minikube service fastapi-service
```

Go to the SwaggerUI and call the APIs to generate logs. You can verify the logs by looking inside the Pod:

```bash
kubectl exec -it <fastapi-deployment-pod> -- sh
```

Navigate to the logs (`cd /var/log/fastapi_app`) and inspect it (`cat my.log`). Also, examine the logs inside the cluster mounted path:

```bash
minikube ssh
```

Go to the logs (`cd /persistent_volume/logs`) and inspect it (`cat my.log`). The two log files have to be identical.

With this setup, if the Pod dies, the logs will be available under the cluster's persistent volume. It will automatically attach the cluster's `/persistent_volume/logs` path to the pod's `/var/log/fastapi_app` path at deployment.

References:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/config-and-storage-resources/persistent-volume-v1/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/common-definitions/node-selector-requirement/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/
- [Docker remove <none> TAG images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33913020/10721627)